# How set height:0?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 horizontally columns with style Float: left.
I want to hide the first block (height:0) but I want that width of the first column was reserved.

display:none or visibility:hidden  not fit my problem...

This code don*t work !**Why?**

```
this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('body_rate')[0].style.height=0+'px';
```

Comment: I can think of two completely different reasons off the top of my head. There isn't enough information in your question to tell which (if any) is right. Try providing a complete reduced test case.

Comment: Also, what does "doesn't work" mean? Does the JavaScript console show errors? Does the style not appear in the DOM inspector view of the element? Does the rendering change, but not in the way you want?

Comment: no errors  but no effects

Comment: So you've looked in a DOM inspector and the style has not been applied to the element?

Comment: You could use `height=1px;visibility:hidden;(font-size:0px;)"`. Setting height to 0px will cause the same effect as setting `display:none`.

Comment: font-size:0 good hack!!!Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try with a combination of `height` and `visibility:hidden`

```
div {
  height:1px;
  visibility:hidden;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Check this demo **http://jsfiddle.net/Z5vnk/8/** with height as `1px`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try giving the column to the right padding equal to the width of the one you're hiding, then hide it.

Comment: I thought about it only with margin. Idea will work but I want better decision.

Answer (score 2):

What if you use `opacity: 0;`? The content is hidden, but if there are some links they are still clickable. You better use `visibility: hidden`.

http://jsfiddle.net/bcsht/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="c c1"><a href="">textA</a></div>
    <div class="c c2">textB</div>
    <div class="c c3">textC</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
.c {
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.c1 {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Visibility hidden should solve the problem, why isn't it ?
Otherwhile, try putting an overflow hidden to your first column.

Comment: if he don't want to keep the space for height visibility doesn't fit the requirements.

Comment: width should be reserved!